# Bottle web server - how to serve PHP file?

Tags: php, python, bottle

I am working on a webapp made by someone else which uses Bottle routing. I want to create a simple login page which requires some PHP. If I return the PHP page as a static_file, any HTML will be executed but PHP won't, for obvious reasons. How should I serve the PHP file so that it is dynamic?

Not working:

```
@route('/login')
def serve():
   return static_file('login.php', root='.')
```

Comment: out of sheer curiosity, why are you writing parts of a python app in php?

Comment: probably because I'm new and clueless. I will write the login in Python, as you and Tom suggested. Not sure how to go about this, but at least I know now that PHP isn't the way to go. Any clues for writing a login system in python? Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In order to server PHP files, you need to have PHP installed on the web server. Additionally, the webserver needs to be configured to detect PHP files and execute them.

Serving PHP files from Python is kinda useless and not recommended.
I'd recommend you to take the time to translate this script from PHP to Python.

Comment: Gotcha. Something like the tutorial "HTTP REQUEST METHODS" here? https://bottlepy.org/docs/dev/tutorial.htm

Answer (score 0):

I wanted to do the same thing yesterday, but the answers I got to my question made it clear it was either impossible or extremely difficult. I came up with writing a small python program to run the PHP built in server. NOTE: PHP needs to be able to run from the command line for this to work.

```
#Import the os package so that this code can run commands
import os

#Get the port that the user wants to host on
port = str(input("What port would you like to host on?"))

#Add wanted port to the command that hosts the php server
cmd = "php -S localhost:" + port

#Actually run the command to host php server
os.system(cmd)

#Now the PHP server will take over until you
#use ctrl + C to quit hosting
```

Just remember that the port needs to be 4 numbers. When you host this, you can return any file from the folder you ran this code in by simply typing it in the browser. Example:

```
localhost:8080/login.php
```

Returns login.php (if it is there) on the localhost port that you asked for.